# Is there an example, s.t. Y is compact, $f$ continuous, bijective, but $f$ is not a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a map between Hausdorff spaces.
>
> Is there an example, s.t. Y is compact, $f$ continuous, bijective, but $f$ is not a homeomorphism.

If $X$ is compact instead of $Y$, then it is clear (the answer is no)

but is $f^{-1}(Y)$ not compact ?

Comment: Let $X$ and $Y$ have the same underlying set, but different topologies.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes i got it. but if we consider $f^{-1}(Y)$, is this not a contradiction ?

Comment: A contradiction to what? $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ for any continous $f\colon X\to Y$.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ has no reason a priori to be continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, consider the set $\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ with the discrete topology for $X$, and with the natural topology induced by the order for $Y$ (where neighborhoods of $\infty$ are the cofinite sets). This $Y$ is compact, but $X$ is not.

Comment: yes, clear. i thought too quickly.(i assumed closed+hausdorff = compact)

Answer (score 3):

I think the classic example of $f : [0,1) \to S^1$ given by $f(x) = e^{2 \pi i x}$ satisfies all your criteria.